# flake8's "# noqa" interferes with markdown using mkdocstrings

Tags: python, flake8, mkdocs, mkdocstrings

I am using [mkdocstrings](https://mkdocstrings.github.io/) in order automatically generate an API documentation from my Python functions. At the same time I am using [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to keep my code in good shape.

If you want to ignore some `flake8` warnings on an in-line basis, you could insert "# noqa" whereby the following lines of code will be ignored by `flake8`.

That's nice, however, "# noqa" will be interpreted by `mkdocstrings` as a markdown header.

Now, I am wondering how to resolve that conflict between `flake8` and `mkdocstrings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the noqa comment on the end of the docstring -- it will apply to any line within the docstring without changing the string's contents (note: you need a sufficiently new flake8, this change is relatively recent (probably >=4.x))

```py
def f():
    """some docstring here

    something which causes a warning
    """  # noqa: ABC123
```

---

disclaimer: I am the current flake8 maintainer